# C++ pointer does not contain expected value?

Tags: c++, operating-system, mingw

I am new to operating system programming and am reading a book which helps make a loader for my c++ operating system. The loader works but my c++ code is not working. I'm trying to print to the text memory location 0xb8000 which is stored in a short pointer. When iterating through the passed in char pointer the values seem to be wrong. It doesn't print out Hello. It just prints out a whole bunch of division symbols with a grey background. [Image of vm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Zkn.png). What can I do to fix this? I'm using nasm mingw's gcc and ld to compile everything.

```
int printf(const char *str);

extern "C" int kernel_main()
{
    printf("Hello");
    return 0;
}

int printf(const char *str)
{
    unsigned short *VideoMemory = (unsigned short *)0xb8000;
    int i = 0;
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        VideoMemory[i] = str[i];
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: *the text memory location 0xb8000* -- What operating system is this?  This looks like old MSDOS programming.

Comment: Maybe, the compiler deletes the part about the VideoMemory part because it thinks that you are not doing anything with it and just returning i. So you can use `volatile` tag when writing to VideoMemory.

Comment: `volatile` is indeed required when using a pointer to a hardware register. This informs the C++ compiler that it may not optimize any dereferences of that pointer (read _or_ write). Change `unsigned short *VideoMemory = (unsigned short *)0xb8000;` to `volatile unsigned short *VideoMemory = (volatile unsigned short *)0xb8000;`.

Comment: If this is in DOS and you want to write directly to the video buffer at 0xB800 you should now that the video memory in text mode is organized in 2 bytes per character: the first byte is the character, the second byte the color (lower 4 bits = foreground, upper 4 bits = background). So you will probably need `VideoMemory[i*2] = str[i];` and for example `VideoMemory[i*2+1] = 0x07;` if you want standard grey on black. (this brings back memories from a very long time ago...)